# What would you call people who attend conferences?

Tags: proper-nouns

What would you call people who attend conferences? Maybe "Attendee"?

Comment: https://velvetchainsaw.com/2010/08/05/registrant-attendee-or-participant-importance-of-right-conference-word/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"attendee" is the common term unless you're referring to a legislative conference:

Compare a google news search for "attendee" vs. "conferee"

Answer (score 2):

**conferee**  [merriam](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conferee)

> one taking part in a conference

Comment: what about "Attendees" is it wrong?

Comment: it is perfectly fine too!

Comment: Both terms are equally applicable – **conferee** is specific to people who attend conferences. An **attendee** can also be somebody who goes to a church service, or listens to a lecture at a local hall, or participates in a funeral service, etc – a general term for someone who attends some function.

Comment: @IconDaemon as far as usage is concerned, conferee seems to be used for a legislative conference only. See Google news searches and the merriam examples.